# My reaction on discord message return nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I try to make a bot that sends a message every morning at 9 o'clock with a possible reaction which for the moment writes me something in the console, the message on discord is sent well but the fact of clicking on l emoji does nothing, can you help me solve my problem? Here is the code:

```js
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.hour = 9;
    rule.minute = 0;
    rule.tz = 'Europe/Paris';
    schedule.scheduleJob(rule, async function() {
        var question = await getQuestion();
        message = await client.channels.cache.get(process.env.CHANNEL_ID).send(`**hello @everyone The wake up question.** \n${question}`)
        message.react('')
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ([''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id);
        };
        message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();
                if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    console.log("message")
                }
            })
    });
```

Comment: make sure, you have the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use message.createReactionCollection() instead of message.awaitReactions().

Here is a code that works for me :

```
msg.react('❌');

const filter1 = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '❌' && user.id === message.author.id;

const collector1 = msg.createReactionCollector(filter1, {time: 60000});
  collector1.on('collect', () => {
  msg.delete();
})

//This is a code that works for me, but in your code you don't want to filter reactions with user.id === message.author.id, as the one who will react isn't the one who sent the message
```

But be careful, as your message is sent automatically every day, don't check if the message author is the one who reacted : remove `user.id === message.author.id`